# Are there i.i.d andom variables $X$ and $Y$ such that either $X+Y$, $X-Y$, $X*Y$ or $X/Y$ is continuously uniformly distributed on some interval?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I think if they are iid it is impossible but I'm not entirely sure...
I tried to calculate pdfs of convoultions/product/ratio distributions and demand that the result is a constant...
But then I did not know how to continue

Anyone has some idea?

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think it is impossible? Please show some of your work. Also leaving the whole question just in the title doesn't look great. please add it to the body. As is the question is likely to get closed for lack of context and detail.

Comment: Updated it - hope it's a bit better now..

Comment: I suggest you look at the unit interval, and the "+" case, and draw some pictures to see whether you can figure out what the distribution on $X$ and $Y$ would *have* to look like. You might also consider a distribution on a discrete set like $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ as a motivator for a continuous solution.

Comment: I think the answer is no, and I think the cleanest path to showing it is roughly: (1) argue why $X$ and $Y$ must be bounded; (2) show that it's impossible for bounded discrete variables; (3) do some obnoxious analysis to adapt that argument for bounded continuous variables. I will note that I could be wrong. (Apologies for the earlier deleted version of this comment, in which I made a silly mistake.)